# declare plugin with digester xmlrules

Tags: apache-commons-digester

I try to write Apache digester parsing rules in xml file (xmlrules). But I don't see something like PluginCreateRule in digester-rules.dtd. The question is: (How) Can I declare and reference plugin in a xml rule file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're out of luck here.

As you've seen, there is no `plugin-create-rule` in the DTD file. Also, Digester uses itself to parse the XML rules, and there is no mention of the `plugin-create-rule` in the [digester configuration itself](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/xref/org/apache/commons/digester3/xmlrules/XmlRulesModule.html).

Looking at that code, it would seem pretty straight forward to add that rule, so I'm not sure if it has been left out just because no-one has gotten around to adding it, or because there are some problems with the implementation which are not immediately obvious.

I would have a go at a patch to implement this, but there appears to be [little activity in Digester](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIGESTER/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) development these days...

**Update**

Yep - seems fairly simple to create a basic implementation which supports this:

- Add a method to `binder/PluginCreateRuleBuilder` to support creation by class name not just class instance (just copied code from `ObjectCreateBuilder`).
- Add a new `xmlrules/PluginCreateRule` class (again, based on `ObjectCreateRule` with most of it thrown away).
- Add the rule to the `XmlRulesModule`.
- Add the rule to the DTD.

Full patch file [here](http://pastebin.com/xd7eNkiL).

Tested using the example from the [Digester Plugin doco](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/guide/plugins.html) with the following XML

```
<digester-rules>
  <pattern value="pipeline">
    <object-create-rule classname="Pipeline"/>
    <pattern value="source">
      <call-method-rule methodname="setSource" paramcount="1"/>
      <call-param-rule paramnumber="0" attrname="file"/>
    </pattern>
    <pattern value="transform">
      <plugin-create-rule pluginclass="Transform"/>
    </pattern>
    <pattern value="destination">
      <call-method-rule methodname="setDest" paramcount="1"/>
      <call-param-rule paramnumber="0" attrname="file"/>
    </pattern>
  </pattern>
</digester-rules>
```

Note that this is only a basic proof-of-concept, but should give you something to work on if you want to go that way. Also, there are a bunch more options for creating plugins which are not covered by this and would be required for a complete solution, so this patch is not (in its current state) suitable for submission back to the Digester project.

**Update 2**

To call this, you need to pass a `PluginRules` instance to the loader when creating a digester:

```
DigesterLoader loader = DigesterLoader.newLoader(new FromXmlRulesModule() {
  ...
});

Digester digester= loader.newDigester(new PluginRules());
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Following the patch, I got an exception in start element: org.apache.commons.digester3.RulesBase cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.digester3.plugins.PluginRules. Maybe I have make a mistake somewhere. Anyway, I decide to just use object-create-rule, for plugin-create-rule will also need an `include` attribute for its own rule files. That's too complex for me to do :(

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer to get past the class cast exception, but if you can get what you need out of the delivered package then that's almost always a better way to go :-)